Where is the SharePoint document library search bar?
In a SharePoint document library, I thought there was a search bar. But I don't seem to find this.
Do I need to enable something?

In SharePoint Online modern experience, search bar for document libraries and lists is moved at the top side.
Example:

You can use the highlighted search box to search files or folders within the SharePoint Online document library.
Related links:

Search experiences in SharePoint
Search box settings on SharePoint sites
Search bar for modern SharePoint doc library


But that top bar allows me to search all document libraries. How do I search in only one document library?

@variable, it's contextual. Will show results from the current library first.

But I want search to only look at current document library. Is that possible?

@variable, When you are inside the document library, by default it shows results only from that particular document library.
